# LSTM output produces invariant output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

This is an example of my training set.

```
k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, k10
48, 45,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 41,  30
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  34
46,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  39
48,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  41
47,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 48,  43
...
```

Every row represents one timestamp. I figured that temporal type of dataset is good in LSTM, so I trained a neural network with multiple layers of LSTM and expected a new set of data. I scaled down the dataset to range `[0,1]` before feeding the model with it. After training of 800 epochs with batch size of 40, every row in the dataset that it produced does not vary with the other. This is the latest output after scaling back up to the original range.

```py
array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
...
```

The neural network model that I compiled is as such

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 1200)          5812800   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 1200)          11524800  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 10, 1200)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 1200)          11524800  
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 1200)              11524800  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1200)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              1201000   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              1001000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 1000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              1001000   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              1001000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 1000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 10)                10010     
=================================================================
Total params: 44,601,210
Trainable params: 44,601,210
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

To my understanding, the higher number of nodes and hidden layers will produce higher number of accuracy.

Is my procedure/understanding incorrect? What can I do to improve my model?

Comment: Did you used return_sequences=True in top 3 lstm layers?

Comment: Yes. As you can see, the output shape for the first three layers are three dimensional while the following layer is only two. `return_sequences=True` for the first three and otherwise for the next layer.